# How to customize a fetch url in React?

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I've finally figured out how to get data from the API :) but now I am stuck because I am trying to change the URL of a fetch request.

I can't figure out how to use my input in the URL as it brings up an error saying input not defined. Which I am assuming is because technically it is not linked. Am I overlooking something really simple?

Also a little background; I am trying to build a simple dictionary web application where you type in a word and it retrieves definitions. I am currently using the WordAPI API for my project.

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import ZipForm from "./ZipForm.js";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      input: "",
    };

    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onFormSubmit(input) {
    this.setState({ input });

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const url = `https://wordsapiv1.p.rapidapi.com/words/${input}/definitions`
    fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "x-rapidapi-host": "wordsapiv1.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "58143f60a0msh9b238a4cf58ba29p1e28e0jsn9e523b0104ba",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({
          items: json,
          isLoaded: true,
        });
        console.log(json.definitions[0].definition);
      });
  }

  render() {
    var { isLoaded, items } = this.state;

    if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="tc">{items.definitions[0].definition}</h1>
        <ZipForm onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: your `componentDidMount` should be `componentDidUpdate`. Also, `input` should be `this.state.input`

Comment: You will also want to guard any use of `items` to make sure it exsits before you use it. For example, that `h1` might become something like `{items && <h1 className="tc">{items.definitions[0].definition}</h1>}`

Comment: Can you explain why I should use DidUpdate vs Mount? The tutorials all say to use Mount. And by guard do you mean setting up error boundaries?

Comment: Sure... you want to do a search every time your component updates, not only when it mounts. In fact, you probably don't even want to search before the user had added any input. When I say "guard", I mean you want to protect against trying to access a property of a non-existent object (for example `items.definitions[0].definition`)

Comment: Yeah that makes perfect sense. Thanks a bunch. And I guess to guard something like that would be to add a variable I think. It's a lot to learn but I'm really enjoying it. tyty

Comment: Wait. Something bad happened because it started constantly sending requests and I racked up over 2500 requests because I didn't realize... If I didn't notice that could've gone worse ._.

Comment: Please look at the React docs here about only fetching data when certain conditions are met. In this case, you probably want to compare the previous input to the current input: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Answer (score 0):

I believe URL should be

```
`https://wordsapiv1.p.rapidapi.com/words/${this.state.input}/definitions`
```